# How to schedule Dataflow Job by running Google Compute Engine cron job

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine, apache-beam, dataflow

In the [Dataflow FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq), it is listed that running custom (cron) job processes on Compute Engine is a way to schedule dataflow pipelines. I am confused about how exactly that should be done: how to start the dataflow job on compute engine and start a cron job.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Google [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs) to execute your Dataflow Job. On Cloud Scheduler you have targets, these could be HTTP/S endpoints, Pub/Sub topics, App Engine applications, you can use your Dataflow template as target. Review this external article to see an example: [Schedule Your Dataflow Batch Jobs With Cloud Scheduler](https://medium.com/@zhongchen/schedule-your-dataflow-batch-jobs-with-cloud-scheduler-8390e0e958eb) or if you want to add more services to the interacion: [Scheduling Dataflow Pipeline using Cloud Run, PubSub and Cloud Scheduler](https://medium.com/@bipinupd/scheduling-dataflow-pipeline-using-cloud-run-pubsub-and-cloud-scheduler-3d10bd6bdb63).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I tried to follow the example, however, despite the service account, the scheduler job always fails to authenticate (PERMISSION DENIED) to the HTTP template endpoint. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: It's difficult say the reason without more information, try search on the logs or the API calls to the Dataflow pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working on App Engine, but I imagine this is similar for Compute Engine

Cron will hit an endpoint on your service at the frequency you specify. So you need to setup a request handler for that endpoint that will launch the dataflow job when hit (essentially in your request handler you need to define your pipeline and then call 'run' on it).

That should be the basics of it. An extra step I do is I have the request handler for my cron job launch a cloud task and then I have the request handler for my cloud task launch the dataflow job. I do this because I've noticed the 'run' command for pipelines sometimes taking a while and cloud tasks have a 10 minute timeout, compared to the 30s timeout for cron jobs (or was it 60s).